# How to write the code for find the median of a variable in stata

Tags: stata, median

I am wondering how to write the codes for finding the median for a variable in stata without using `sort`, `egen`, `summarize`. This is what I got so far:

```
capture program drop find_median
program find_median
    local n = _N
    gen ord=0
    forvalues i= 0/`n' {
        replace ord = `i' if [`1']> [`1'][_n-1] & [`1']> [`1'][_n+1] 
    }
end

find_median (the variables...)
```

Comment: Note that your own looping over observations is doomed to be much, much slower than Stata's internal code.

Answer (score 2):

The `centile` command gives you the median directly.

If you insist on recreating the wheel then you can use `sort` inside your program but leave the sortorder of the data unchanged after the program ends by adding the `sortpreserve` option to the line `program find_median`, see: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?program. That should make the program much simpler and thus easier to debug.

Comment: Specifically, you need to "centile myvar" then you have access to "r(c_1)", which is the median, or close enough to it. In my data set, the actual center value is exactly 7.3733, and the centile-based median is reported as 7.373301. Strange, but close enough.